# How to download npm packages instead of using the command line

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-applications, offline

I'm working in a completely offline environment & lately, I've had to code some react applications. I wonder if there is a way to download `npmjs` packages manually without using the command `npm install <package-name>`.

For example, while I'm coding with python in the same offline env, I'm downloading everything from PyPi manually & use the `.whl` in my offline environment using removable devices from one online environment to the offline environment.

I'll appreciate for any help or direction to the solution.

Comment: No matter whether they're downloaded "manually" or through npm, you'll have to have an internet connection to do the download. Why not just use npm while you have the connection? Using node modules while offline isn't a problem. I don't really understand what the goal is here.

Comment: I have two stations: one with an internet connection & the second without an internet connection. all my work has to be done within the offline station.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to download their source from the github. Find the main file and then include it in your main file.

You need to find the source and go through the package.json file. There you can find which is the main file. So that you can include that in your application.

To include example.js in your app. Copy it into your application folder.
Once you do that, your requirements will just be:

var moduleName = require("path/to/example.js")

It will always look for a node_modules directory at the root of your app (and a few other places as well).

It's important you download the full repo and not just the lib folder if you plan to use it this way since the package.json file is used to find the main entry point. As long as the repository has a valid package.json file it should work.[[image: As an example if you want express you go to the packages repo.]